# What does "Got an error handling event: Dwarf Error: Cannot find type of die" mean?

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, gdb, macports

I'm trying to debug a hang on an old Apple PowerMac G5. The program is C++11, and it was created using MacPorts GCC 5.4. <strike>MacPorts also supplies the debugger, which is GDB 6.3.</strike>

Under the debugger I see:

```
...
Catchpoint 1 (exception thrown).
Catchpoint 1 (exception caught), throw location assert.cpp:33, catch location unknown, exception type Botan::Exception
0x009903ec      110           { ::operator delete(__p); }
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Util load/store ran 229 tests all ok
Util round_down ran 6 tests in 0.11 msec all ok
Util round_up ran 11 tests in 22.56 sec all ok
Die: DW_TAG_unspecified_type (abbrev = 3, offset = 247)
        has children: FALSE
        attributes:
                DW_AT_name (DW_FORM_string) string: "decltype(nullptr)"
warning: Got an error handling event: "Dwarf Error: Cannot find type of die [in module /Users/botan/libbotan-1.11.35.35.dylib]".
```

After the above, things just hang. I can <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> and Continue, but I seem to flop around `_Unwind_RaiseException ()` and `_Unwind_GetIPInfo ()`.

What does ***`Got an error handling event: "Dwarf Error: Cannot find type of die`*** mean?

---

I've found a couple of related questions, but they are not very satisfying and don't explain much:

- [Dwarf Error: Cannot find DIE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6325661)
- [iceweasel: randomly crashes by receiving from X the following: ABORT: Request 155.34: BadLength](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=642537)

I also can't seem to get a decent backtrace:

```
(gdb) bt full
#0  0x009903ec in __cxa_throw () at ext/new_allocator.h:110
No symbol table info available.
Die: DW_TAG_unspecified_type (abbrev = 3, offset = 247)
        has children: FALSE
        attributes:
                DW_AT_name (DW_FORM_string) string: "decltype(nullptr)"
Dwarf Error: Cannot find type of die [in module /Users/botan/libbotan-1.11.35.35.dylib]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [weird gdb message when debugging C++ program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621461/weird-gdb-message-when-debugging-c-program)

Comment: GDB 6.3 is very very old for GCC 5.4. It was released in 2004, 7 years before C++11.

Comment: @ks1322 - Thanks. Please forgive my ignorance... Is the cited question *also* the cause of the message *"Got an error handling event: "Dwarf Error: Cannot find type of die"*? The answer does not discuss it. It seems like it should be in the answer if its related or part of the problem.

Comment: I think that yes. Probably "Got an error handling event: "Dwarf Error: Cannot find type of die" message was not copy pasted in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621461/weird-gdb-message-when-debugging-c-program. Still it looks very related to your question and solution is to upgrade gdb to a latest version.